# Run a Procedure in another form

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that runs a procedure to create an email in Outlook and attach a pdf to it. Its record source is a non-updatable query. The procedure runs fine. I now want to run that procedure from another form but I keep getting a message saying that it can't be done because the record source is not updatable. The coding in the new form is:

```
Private Sub CourseCert_Click()
On Error GoTo CourseCert_Click_Err

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCourseDetailsDone", acNormal, "", "[StaffLookup]=" & [StaffLookup], , acNormal
Run Forms!frmCourseDetailsDone.Command23_Click
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmCourseDetailsDone"

CourseCert_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

CourseCert_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume CourseCert_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Since it works in the old form I can't see why it won't work from the new form.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
Forms!frmCourseDetailsDone.Command23_Click
```

I would make the code Command23_Click a public procedure and then call the procedure directly instead of referring to a button in another form.

```
Public sub Command23_Click() 

Call Command23_Click
```

Answer (score 1):

> Calling sub in a form

```
Form_frmName.PublicSubName(anyVars)
```

Example -

```
Form_NewClient.SetID()
```

> Calling Sub from another module

```
Call MyPublicSub
```

Example -

```
Call SetID()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it like this to get it working as public function in form did not work

```vb
'--- In Form Materials
Private Sub Calc_Click()
    Select Case Me.CATEGORY
    Case "Ply"
        On Error Resume Next
        'CurrentDb.Execute Forms![CASE].GetPlyQty
        Run Forms![CASE].GetPlyQty
        Me.Qty = PlyQty '(PlyQty is in Globals module)
End Select
End Sub

'--- In Globals module
Public PlyQty As Double


'--- In form "Case"
Public Sub GetPlyQty()
    Dim paintarea As Double
    PlyQty = CalcPly(paintarea)
End Sub
```