# Accessing Events in a Form Object

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to create an instance of a form object, modify a value, run an event, and finally export it to PDF.  I can successfully instantiate the object, modify its controls, and export to PDF.  Where I am struggling is how to get a particular event to fire.  In this situation, I want to fire the cboBusinessUnit_AfterUpdate event.

My goal is to run this activity in the background, without visibly seeing the form object.  Any suggestions on how I can call events within my form object?

```
Private Sub cmdExportPDF_Click()
Dim frm As Form

'test for null combobox
If Nz(Me.cboBusinessUnit, 0) <> 0 Then

    Set frm = New Form_frmStaffingChart

    frm.Controls("cboBusinessUnit").Value = Me.cboBusinessUnit

    '***Need to fire the cboBusinessUnit_AfterUpdate event here***

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, frm.Name, acFormatPDF, , True

Set frm = Nothing
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984762/run-a-procedure-in-another-form   It explains how to call a procedure in a different object.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it generates a compiler error  " Expected: = "

Comment: I just opened a form, entered the following into the immediate window '?Forms!Applicants.Form_AfterUpdate' and it ran just fine.  Did you declare the procedure as 'Public'? Please post the entire line that gets the compile error.